# C++ template deduction from lambda

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function which takes two `std::function`s as arguments. The parameter of the second function has the same type as the result of the first.

I wrote a function template like this:

```
template<typename ResultType>
void examplFunction(std::function<ResultType()> func, std::function<void(ResultType)> func2) {
  auto x = func();
  func2(x);
}
```

I can call it with:

```
void f() {
  examplFunction<int>([]() { return 1; },   //
                      [](int v) { std::cout << "result is " << v << std::endl; });
}
```

Is there a way to to get rid of the `<int>` at `examplFunction<int>` and let the compiler deduce the type of `ResultType`?

Comment: Lambdas are not `std::function`s.  `std::function`s are type erasure tools.  Type deduction and type erasure are opposites of each other.  If you are deducing the type of a type erasure tool you are almost always screwing up.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Do you actually need `std::function` in there? `std::function` is useful when you need *type erasure*. With templates, you can usually skip it altogether:

```
template<class F1, class F2>
void examplFunction(F1 func, F2 func2, decltype(func2(func()))* sfinae = nullptr) {
  auto x = func();
  func2(x);
}
```

The `sfinae` parameter makes sure the function can only be called with functions such that `func2` can be called with the result of `func`.

Comment: Note that your SFINAE is not actually corresponding to the implementation. If `func` returned a move-only type (say, `std::unique_ptr`) then the SFINAE would allow it but the function body wouldn't compile. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/luZiop).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yes, but the exact same issue applies to the OP's original code. The SFINAE is only there to guarantee what the OP asked for.

Comment: True I guess. I'm left to wonder if this can somehow be broken with implicit conversions (and an overloaded `func2`)... But I don't see a way.

Comment: Hmm it seems to do what it should. But the `decltype(func2(func()))* sfinae = nullptr` looks very magical to me. How can a third function argument restrict the first and second?

Comment: @ErWu https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE Basically, if `func2(func())` would be ill-formed, it prevents the template from being instantiated.

Comment: Now I got it. :)

Comment: @Angew: Is there any reason to use a dummy argument instead of the return type here? I've only ever used dummy arguments for constructors.

Comment: @MatthieuM. No, there is no reason. It was just the first thing that came to mind. A template parameter with default argument or the return type would work just as well.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is.

```
template<typename ResultType>
void examplFunction_impl(std::function<ResultType()> func, std::function<void(ResultType)> func2) {
    auto x = func();
    func2(x);
}

template<class F1, class F2>
void examplFunction(F1&& f1, F2&& f2)
{
    using ResultType = decltype(f1());
    examplFunction_impl<ResultType>(std::forward<F1>(f1), std::forward<F2>(f2));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/QP8Ryq)

In this case you require that `f1` be invocable with no arguments, so you can figure out the return type in the helper function. Then you call the real function while explicitly specifying that return type.

You could add some [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) to make sure this function only participates in overload resolution when `f1` can indeed be invoked like that (and if `f2` can also be invoked with the return value of `f1`).

Although I have to agree with @Angew that *in the given example* there is no need for `std::function`. That might of course be different in a real-world situation.

Answer (score 3):

`std::function` has a templated (and otherwise unconstrained) constructor, so deducing it from simply an argument type is not that easy a deal. If those arguments still need to be `std::function`s, you can skip one `<int>` for the price of two `std::function`s, and let deduction guides do the rest:

```
void f() {
    examplFunction(std::function([]() { return 1; }),   //
                   std::function([](int v) { std::cout << "result is "
                                             << v << std::endl; }));
}
```

A fun fact is that this does not always work. For instance, the current implementation of libc++ lacks guides for `std::function`, thus violating the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Angew's answer is great (and should be the accepted answer), but is missing the minor detail of checking that the section function doesn't return anything. To do that you'll need to use the `std::is_void` type trait, and std::enable_if:

```
template<class F1, class F2>
void examplFunction(F1 func, F2 func2, std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<decltype(func2(func()))>, void*> sfinae = nullptr) {
    auto x = func();
    func2(x);
}
```

This obvious is more verbose and difficult to read if you aren't familiar with type traits and SFINAE, so it probably isn't the best way forward if you don't need to make sure F2 returns `void`.

Comment: The OP's original code doesn't require that `func2` return `void`. `std::function<void(ResultType)>` is constructible-from a function that returns something; it'll just cast the return value to `void`, which is to say, it'll ignore it. `std::function<void()>( []() { return 42; } )` [compiles just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/MFMb3a).